# Finding the Newton map

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods

> Start with $p(x)=(x-x_0)^k g(x)$. I need to find the Newton map, which is $Np(x)=x−p(x)/p'(x)$.

Is $p'(x)=k(x-x_0)^{k-1}g(x)+(x-x_0)^kg'(x)$?

I'm having a tough time with $k$ and $x_0$.

Comment: You differentiated that correctly. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I need to find the Newton map, which is $N_p(x)=x-p(x)/p'(x)$. I'm just having a hard time converting this equation.

Answer (score 2):

If $x_0$ and $k$ are constants with respect to the variable $x$, then $p'(x)$ is as you described it.  We can also write it as $$p'(x) = (x-x_0)^{k-1} (k g(x) + (x-x_0)g'(x))$$ after factorization.  If, however, $x_0$ or $k$ are functions of $x$, then the derivative of $p$ with respect to $x$ must take that into account accordingly, in as much as we did when we differentiated $g(x)$ with respect to $x$ because $g$ is understood to be some (unspecified) function of $x$.

It follows that $$\begin{align*} N_p(x) &= x - \frac{p(x)}{p'(x)} \\ &= x - \frac{(x-x_0)^k g(x)}{(x-x_0)^{k-1}(k g(x) + (x-x_0) g'(x))} \\ &= x - \frac{(x-x_0)g(x)}{k g(x) + (x-x_0)g'(x)}  \\ &= x - \frac{x-x_0}{k + (x-x_0)(g'(x)/g(x))}. \end{align*}$$